# can someone explain odd behavor of character array kchar1 in the sample c++ program below

Tags: c++, char

I am a new c++ programmer and ran into some char array behavior that I can't explain.  This is strictly a learning exercise for me.

I understand why kchar and kchar1 display as they do for values of j equal to 0 through 5 but can't understand why k1 displays extra characters when j = 6 and 7.  I also can't explain why kchar displays a value of 7 for kchar[0] when j = 7.

Thanks in advance.

Ken_SF

output observed for j = 6 and 7:

j = 6
k : '10111010'
k1: '012345610111010'

j = 7
k : '70111011'
k1: '012345670111011'

end output, code shown next:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

char buf[] = "101110111101110111011110110111011101101110111011101110111110111011101110111011011";
char kchar[] = "00000000";//interesting kchar[7]; gives weird results when you display kchar for many iterations
char kchar1[7];
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++){
            kchar[j] = buf[j];
            kchar1[j] = j + '0';
             cout << "j = " << j << endl;
             cout << "k : '" << kchar << "'" << endl;
             cout << "k1: '" << kchar1 <<  "'" << endl;
             cout << endl;
  }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = 0 ; j < 8 ; j++){` is an off by 1 error. Should be `for (int j = 0 ; j < 7 ; j++){` if you have `kchar1[7]`

Comment: I figured it out. change kchar1[7] to kchar1[9] and set a termination character kchar1[8] = '\0'    I hope this helps someone else in the future. Ken_SF

Comment: Pro tip: never use C-style arrays. Always use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: That is very good advice from @JesperJuhl

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a minor bug that the OP solved in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you to all who responded.  I should have been savvy enough to see my error before posting even though I am a new c++ programmer.  I realize std::array and std::vector are preferred in c++ but thought I should fully understand char array use as well since I am learning.  This exercise emphasized (to me) that char arrays are declared using a 1 based count and referenced with a zero based count.  arr[4]="foo";  is correct (but not preferred style) in c++ yet we reference arr using zero based count (the 2nd character in arr is arr[1];  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply your program runs an Undefined Behavior: because `kchar1` has 7 elements but your loop iterates to `j = 7` so `kchar1[7]` is Undefined Behavior that is why you get invalid character. So the last character in `kchar1` is `kchar1[6]` not `kchar1[]7`.

- Also there is another Undefined Behavior: `kchar1` must have a Null-terminator character `\0` as the last element:

  ```
  // inside loop:
  if(j < 7 - 1)
      kchar1[j] = j + '0';
  kchar1[6] = '\0';
  ```